# Lenovo Laptop Dims always on reboot

Tags: brightness

I always have to press by Fn + Brightness increase key in Ubuntu. I have switched off all the power management and still this happens. I am on a Lenovo ideapad U260 and can't to seem to set the brightness to same constant (high) at all times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can script this with **xbacklight**:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

`xbacklight -set 100` will set your brightness to 100%. You can add this as a new startup application (Search for 'Startup Applications', or I believe it's accessible by clicking the icon in the top right corner), or add this command to `/etc/rc.local` if you want it to happen earlier in the boot sequence

Comment: I think, this should do. I might take time to reboot and test it, but without reboot xbacklight work and I believe it could work as a startup application too. Thanks.