# Brightness resets to zero on an HP dm4 Pavilion

Tags: brightness

Everytime I reboot my HP dm4 Pavillion the brightness is zero on my screen. BTW I use a Ubuntu 12.04..

Comment: Is that the darkest, lowest setting?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/93038/lenovo-laptop-dims-always-on-reboot?rq=1 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/97561/brightness-setting-is-reset-to-maximum-at-login?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

edit the file /etc/rc.local

before the last line 'exit 0'  add the following line:

echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

save and reboot.

This should then set your brightness.  I will add the caveat that this doesn't always work with HP machines but hopefully you'll be OK.